# CakePHP 3.2: Prevent authError showing when user is not logged in

Tags: authentication, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.0

Even when user is not logged in and tries to open homepage, after being redirected to login page, authError is displayed.Is there an elegant way to prevent this, without modifying Auth component? This is how I load Auth component(I am using TinyAuth as authorization adapter):

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ],
                'loginRedirect' => [
                   'controller' => 'Home',
                   'action' => 'index'
                ],
                'authError' => 'You dont have permissions for that action',
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                        ],
                        'scope' => ['Users.active' => true],
                        'contain' => ['Roles']
                    ]
                ],
                'authorize' => [
                    'TinyAuth.Tiny' => [
                        'roleColumn' => 'role_id',
                        'rolesTable' => 'Roles',
                        'multiRole' => true,
                        'pivotTable' => 'roles_users',
                        'superAdminRole' => null,
                        'authorizeByPrefix' => false,
                        'prefixes' => [],
                        'allowUser' => false,
                        'adminPrefix' => null,
                        'autoClearCache' => true
                    ] 
                ]
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [CakePHP's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages) you can prevent the error message from being shown by setting `authError` to `false`.

> Sometimes, you want to display the authorization error only after the
>   user has already logged-in. You can suppress this message by setting
>   its value to boolean false.

This should disable the error message:

```
if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
    $this->Auth->config('authError', false);
}
```

Comment: where should I add this code . in Appcontroller beforefileter or somewhere else.

Comment: The documentation mentions that you should use this in the `beforeFilter()`. :).

Comment: use setConfig since cakePHP 4